# ISA Card Mechanical Drawing Source

Tags: pcb-design

I'm designing a new ISA form factor PC board for a legacy system.  I've looked around the net and found several references for ISA board dimensions, but they don't call out the location of the edge card connector fingers with respect to the front panel edge of the card.

**Does anyone know where to find a reliable ISA board outline, including the relative location of the edge card contacts to the front panel edge?**

One possible source of the mechanical specificaitons is IEEE P996, a proposed standard for the ISA bus that was apparently never finalized, but it does not seem to be available any more.

Comment: found this .... http://www.interfacebus.com/Design_PCAT_Card.html   .......... what do you mean by `front panel edge of the card`?

Comment: @jsotola In that drawing, it would be the right hand edge.  The drawing only gives the outline dimensions, but not the location of the edge connectors with respect the outline.  I'm also looking for more of an original/trustworthy source

Comment: I think part of the problem is that it never was a standard.  I suspect that serious ISA board designers (aside from people working at IBM) had a drawer full of boards and a decent caliper, and their own personal drawing.  IIRC, the connector captures the tab pretty well, and the bracket allows for some slop -- if you can find a spec for the connector it should spec the tab, and if you get the bracket a little bit wrong you should still be OK.

Comment: maybe the best thing to do is to find a scrap computer that contains some ISA boards and measure the boards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mechanical drawings in section 2.12 of the Extended Industry Standard Architecture (EISA) Specification 3.1. Figures 95 and 96 show the dimensions for a 16-bit ISA card. There are dimensions given showing the distance to the outside face of the mounting bracket. I've designed and produced ISA cards with these dimensions with both 3d-printed and sheet metal mounting brackets, and they fit perfectly in various old computers.

A PDF of the spec is available at the OS2 Museum Website [here](https://www.os2museum.com/files/docs/EISA_Specification-v3.1.pdf).  The drawings start on specification page number 249, which is on PDF page 220.

Answer (score 1):

I would look on

http://bitsavers.org

http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/pc/

The retro-computing Stack-Exchange site may also have some good info.

Answer (score 0):

There may very well be a outline in the original PC-XT and/or PC-AT Hardware Reference Manual, mine were 3 ring binders. A lot of the circuit diagrams for the add on cards were included.  These may be for sale second hand somewhere.

I remember using the dimension data from a instruction sheet from a Universal breadboard card that was sold by RS components (of UK, not the US Radio Shack) for this purpose.  See if someone is still selling a prototyping card with decent documentation online.

You should be able to get adequate accuracy by measuring half a dozen diverse samples as the tolerances were huge or ignored.  Very rarely was a card a tight fit and sometimes they did require loosening of the back plate to make them fit well.

In fact you r easiest is to search the net for a few PCB layouts or Gerber files and use them for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I think we can safely assume that the fingers are centered within their PCB cutouts. A standard 31-position 0.1" edge connector receptacle has 3.0" (76.2mm) between the centers of the first and last fingers, and the slot for the board is dimensioned at exactly 3.2" (81.28mm). The center of the finger nearest an edge is then 0.1" (2.54mm) from the end of the slot.

The [diagram given in the comments](http://www.interfacebus.com/Design_PCAT_Card.html), though, shows the relevant PCB dimension at 81.02mm, which is less than the slot diameter by 0.26mm (a hundredth of an inch). Taking half of that from each side, the centers of the fingers should be 2.41mm from the PCB cuts.

Working again from the diagram, the cut for J1 begins 22.65mm from the edge of the board, so the center of the first finger should be 25.06mm from the board edge. Although, half a mm either way in finger positioning probably doesn't even matter, as long as the board physically fits.